# "Swipe to go back" gesture doesn't work properly in WatchOS

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

In all of the WatchOS applications I tried (except Apple's own apps), including the one I'm developing, I've noticed that once I swipe from the left edge of the screen to go back to the previous one, I can sometimes no longer go to any other screen by tapping to any one of the buttons on the screen.

This seems like a serious bug, which becomes more prominent once you try to go back a few times by swiping in the main interface controller and then tap on any one of the buttons on the interface that pushes another screen. It only pushes another screen once you swipe back again, and with a buggy animation. This is really weird.

Is there any way to disable that gesture?

Also, has anyone reported this to Apple?

Comment: Did you get the solution for that ?

Comment: No, I reported it as a bug.

Comment: Ok, Did you find any work around for the same. In my app when I do ship back 2 times from my root interface controller then it will hangs the UI and I can't go to other interface controller.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Thank's to Apple's great QA,  users will think that it is our fault. I can't believe how did they manage to ship the OS with a major bug like this.

Comment: I meet the same issue 3.1.3(14S960)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, which I, along with several other people, have reported it to Apple. Unfortunately, there is no way to disable this behavior currently.